# XML inside XML how to use in Base X

Tags: xml, basex

I have a project that is to analyse XML documents with the software Base X

My problem is that my XML file is like the model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
...
```

in other words, it's lots of XML inside this one XML, and when I try to open it with Base X, I get the error:

`O destino da instrução de processamento correspondente "[xX][mM][lL]" não é permitido.`, roughly translating to english is the above

```
The instruction destiny of processing "[xX][mM][lL]" isn't allowed.
```

how to?

Comment: You'll have a hard time, as this is no well-formed XML document. You might be able to split them apart using the [read functions in the `file:` module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#Read_Operations) followed by [`fn:parse-xml`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml). But if anybody promised you XML input, tell him to send you proper, well-formed XML, as this isn't and working with it will be tedious, cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it'll be tedious..but I kind of do not have a choice..it's a collection of XMLs that are disponibilized only in this way, it's like for every day on the week, there's a XML, and when the week is finished, they join it all on 1 and disponibilize it to download..I guess I'll try the parsing method to several XMLs files on a buffer and use it on separate files..like you said, tedious ;~

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple XML snippets without document declarations, you could as well use `fn:parse-xml-fragment("...")`; but this wouldn’t work in your case.

The following XQuery helps you to split the contents of your input file and store it in a BaseX database. It should work out of the box if your input is not too huge, and if all new documents start with a document declaration (`<?xml`...); otherwise, you will have to modify it a little:

```
let $lines := unparsed-text-lines('your-input.txt')
let $docs :=
  for tumbling window $doc-lines in $lines
  start $start when true()
  end next $next when starts-with($next, '<?xml')
  return parse-xml(string-join($doc-lines, '&#xa;'))
count $count
let $names :=
  for $doc at $pos in $docs
  return 'doc' || $pos || '.xml'
return db:create('your-database', $docs, $names)
```